# Use .onReceive code in multiple instances - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "onboardingView" {
                OnboardingView()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPage == "homeView" {
                TabView {
                    HomeView(mealsController: self.mealsController)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Text("Menu")
                    }
                    SettingsView(mealsController: self.mealsController)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                            Text("Settings")
                    }
                }
                .accentColor(Color(getThemeConstants.accentThemeColor))
            }
        }
```

on the bottom of that I have:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
...
}
.onAppear() {
...
}
```

inside `.onReceive` I have a bunch of code that I need to reuse on `.onAppear`, how can I reuse this kind of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract common code in some private function and call it from both modifiers, like below

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
   self.handlerFunction()
}
.onAppear() {
   self.handlerFunction()
}

...

private func handlerFunction() {
   // move common code here
}
```